# Icons animation in input field

Tags: html, css, input

Im making a user registration page. It is necessary to make it so that when you click on one of the input fields, the left standing icon appears in the same place (in the input field) But if the user has not yet clicked on this input field, the icon should not be displayed, and it is already done by the css property `transition: all 0.5s;`.**But the problem is that**, when you wrote you information is input filed, and start writing in another, the icon in the last input disappears(what shouldn`t be).And also I want to do that, the text in input field will slightly move at right, when the user clicked on it,and will be shown an icon(of course by the deafult the text need to be at the left side).

Everything is desirable to be done in CSS, in JS it is also possible.

[My registration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbsvJ.png)

So far, the code looks like this (HTML):

```
<div className="input-form">
                    <input
                    type="text" value={name} className="has-icon-user" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Name, Surname" />
                </div>
                <div className="input-form">
                    <input
                    type="email" value={email} className="has-icon-email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="E-mail" />
                </div>
                <div className="input-form">

                    <input type="password" value={password} className="has-icon-password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>


                <button onClick={login} type="submit">Register</button>
                <p onClick={alreadyHaveProfile}>I have a profile</p>
```

And my CSS:

```
  >.input-form>input[type=number],
  input[type=text],
  input[type=email],
  input[type=password] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    padding-left:55px; 
  }
  >.input-form>.has-icon-user:focus{
    background-image:url("images/user.svg") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-position: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  >.input-form>.has-icon-email:focus{
    background-image:url("images/email.svg");
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    
  } 
  >.input-form>.has-icon-password:focus{
    background-image:url("images/lock.svg") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    
  }
```

I hope for your answer!

Comment: What about this: **If input.value = " " = icon display: none; else display: block;**

Comment: And what about animation?

Comment: You could try it with `opacity: 0;` and `opacity: 1;` **OR** `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;`